# Installing Python Twisted on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, twisted

Trying to install Twisted on my computer (Mac OS X with El Capitan beta), but when I try to run any code, it says that it can't find the twisted module.

I think something in my path is incorrect, but I can't figure out what it is - it looks like twisted is installed in the correct location (python/site-packages), but python can't find it when I try to import it.

```
➜ ~ git:(master) ✗ python -V
    Python 2.7.6
➜ ~ git:(master) ✗ pip -V
    pip 7.1.0 from /Users/camherringshaw/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (python 2.7)
➜ ~ git:(master) ✗ pip install twisted
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twisted in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twisted)
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
➜ ~ git:(master) ✗ python -c 'import twisted'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named twisted
➜ ~ git:(master) ✗ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole smattering of mistaken assumptions in your question, so rather than one answer, here are just some interesting relevant facts.

- If you want to add directories to allow Python to import things, set `PYTHONPATH`, not `PATH`.
- It looks like you are mixing homebrew python (installed in `/usr/local/`) and system python (installed in `/usr`).  Your examples here are using system python but if stuff is getting installed in `/usr/local/lib/` then at some point you were most likely using Homebrew.
- If you want `pip` to put stuff into `~/Library`, you should do `pip install --user`, not move files around from your system install.  If you manually relocate a package like that, chances are good you will forget a file, such as an `.egg-info` or a manifest or some data files; it's pip job to remember that stuff, not yours.  Also, by moving packages manually, you make it impossible for pip to properly *un*-install them.
- Finally, you should really only ever install stuff into a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) if you can help it.  This makes it a lot easier to recover from your mistakes.  If you `sudo pip install` stuff or put things into `/usr/local`, the worst case scenario is having to reinstall your operating system; if you use `pip install --user` the worst case is you have to delete your entire user account.  If you're using virtualenv though, the worst case is just deleting a directory and trying again.

Comment: Okay, so in my fish configuration, I should set `PYTHONPATH` to the location of the pip installs?
I think I did have python installed through Homebrew, but I've removed that and taken it out of my path, so I think it's just using the system version. At least, when I use `which` with python, it's in /usr/bin, but when I check `which pip`, it's in /usr/local/bin/pip. Not sure whether that's correct or not.
Ended up setting up virtualenv, and I'm now using that instead of pip install --user. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Generally you should avoid setting `PYTHONPATH`, since that means every virtualenv gets extra junk added to its `sys.path`, whereas the whole point of virtualenv is to have nice isolated environments that only have what they need.  So you need to set `PYTHONPATH` once to get your first `pip` installation done, but after that, just work out of virtualenvs and ignore `PYTHONPATH` :)

Comment: Ah, okay, got it. Think I've got virtualenvs working now, and without using `PYTHONPATH`. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, leaving this here in case anyone else sees a similar issue.

pip was installing to the incorrect directory - all of my other Python imports were in ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages, which also was not on my path. To fix it, I moved the twisted directory from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages to ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages, and added the correct directory to my path.

Haven't figured out how to change the install directory for pip (other than by using the --target flag every time), but this fixes it for now.